# Drawing from InverseWishartMatrixDistribution. A machine precision error?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra, random, machine-precision

I'm drawing from the Inverse-Wishart Distribution, but I got the following error message:

```
InverseWishartMatrixDistribution::posdefprm: 
   The value {{768.252, 317.247, 737.618}, {317.247, 180.387, 305.871}, 
     {737.618, 305.871, 708.24}} at position 2 in 
    InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[10, 
     {{768.252, 317.247, 737.618}, {317.247, 180.387, 305.871}, 
      {737.618, 305.871, 708.24}}] is expected to be a symmetric positive
     definite matrix.
```

Well, when I do `SymmetricMatrixQ` and `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ`, I get True for the matrix shown... It's probably that Mathematica has approximated the true values in the error message.

The problem lies, I suspect elsewhere. The code I use is the following:

```
RandomVariate[
 InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[nu, mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1)]]
```

If `mean` is PD and Sym, then `mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1)` with nu=10 and Length[mean]=3 should also be...

I make sure that mean is PD and Sym with the another programme, let us call it SPDMatrix.

So, I think that the problem maybe that InverseWishartMatrixDistribution may somehow use greater machine precision functions like SymmetricMatrixQ and PositiveDefiniteQ than those available to the users...

I've managed to replicate the problem in a simpler way:

```
In[102]:= RandomSeed[1234];
list = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {100000, 3, 3}];

In[105]:= 
list2 = ParallelTable[
    SPDMatrix[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]*14;

In[107]:= Map[SymmetricMatrixQ, list2] // Total

Out[107]= 100000 True

In[106]:= Map[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ, list2] // Total

Out[106]= 22234 False + 77766 True

In[108]:= 
list3 = ParallelTable[
   SPDMatrix[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}];

In[109]:= Map[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ, list3] // Total

Out[109]= 100000 True
```

The difference between list2 and list3 is that in list 2 I've multiplied by 14... This must interfere with the machine precision.

Comment: Can you give an *explicit* SPD matrix `mat` such that `RandomVariate[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[n, mat]]` throws an error message? Copying your matrix `{{768.252, 317.247, 737.618}, {317.247, 180.387, 305.871}, {737.618, 305.871, 708.24}}` into *Mathematica* and using it in the distribution shows no problems.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I'm running my code on a server, to which I have no interface. (I'm windows, and the server is linux, so I just run a .m file). So, the only way I have of detecting this is by using SymmetricMatrixQ, and PositiveDefiniteQ, which do NOT detect the problem....

Comment: Can't you modify your code such that it returns `InputForm[mean (nu + Length[mean] + 1)]` whenever a failure is encountered?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Probably. Do you know of a way to create a condition for when Mathematica emits an error message to print that Inputform?  Otherwise, it would need to print possibly a few thousands of matrices before we get the one we want...

Comment: Sure, insert a line like `Check[RandomVariate[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[nu, mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1)]], Return[InputForm[mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1)]], General::posdefprm]` in the relevant section of your code. (Thankfully, you were thoughtful enough to mention what error message was being returned.)

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive thanks for the code. I managed to replicate the problem in a simpler way... I've edited the question to reflect that new information. ;)

Comment: I have to say, you have an interesting way of counting `True` and `False` results. (Use `Tally[]` or `Counts[]` next time.)

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. ;)

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I think I now understando how I must correct my code... Should I just delete this question?

Comment: I'd say it's better for you to write an answer to your own question, so other people can learn from what you did.

Comment: Why not `Rationalize` mean first to avoid precision issues? For example: `(Rationalize[mean, 0](nu + Length[mean] + 1)`

Comment: @CarlWoll First time reading about that function. Would it preserve the SPD properties of mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, instead of just making sure that mean is SPD, I could just create a new function to draw from Inverse-Wishart, but making sure that mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1) is SPD... Here's an example

```
drawIW[mean_, s2_] := Module[{matrix},
   nu = 10;
   matrix = SPDMatrix[mean*(nu + Length[mean] + 1)];
   (*We need this, since sometimes multiplying by nu+Length[
   mean]+1 will return a non-
   SPD matrix due to machine precision considerations... *)

   RandomVariate[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[nu, matrix]]
   ];
```